# How to work with a lot of folders in Visual Studio, each has its own Makefile

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm currently taking a course on C++. All code for this course has approximately this structure:

```
cpp-class (folder)
  - Cube.cpp
  - Cube.h
  - main.cpp
  - Makefile
cpp-memory (folder):
  - main.cpp
  - foo.cpp
  - Makefile
```

and so on, many folders.
To run a script, the teacher heads to a directory, runs `make`, and then runs the script, all in a terminal.
I want to know, whether there is a way to work with all of this code as one project (or solution) in Visual Studio, such that I don't open each folder as a solution.

Comment: Yes, Visual Studio can have a single solution with many independent projects.

Comment: So you want to run all Makefiles in the subdirectories with one command , right ?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Lazarakis Not exactly. I want to run and build the scripts easily. For example, I right-click a main.cpp in Solution explorer. I don't see any options to run it.

Comment: Also, I don't understand how to choose a file for debugging

Comment: IIRC you can have only one *active* project at a time in your solution. Select the project you're currently working on, and "Run" or "Debug" as usual. Assuming you have imported the makefiles into the Visual Studio solution/project format.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I can't run or debug, they are greyed out.I didn't import makefiles into VS and I'm not sure they are compatible with VS format. A teacher `make` them in Linux

Comment: [How to import makefiles into Visual Studio](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0d553684-d589-4e5f-b04d-9b799f6d2e44/import-a-makefile-project?forum=Vsexpressvc) If that doesn't work, put that sentence into your favorite search engine for more.